# how to show multiple images in Django admin panel

Tags: python, django

I am using this to show image in my Django admin panel but is there any way of showing multiple images :

```
def product_Image(self):
    """Method to return store image for admin panel"""

    return '<img src="/images/%s" height="150" width="150"/>' % self.image_paths
product_Image.allow_tags = True
```

But if `self.image_paths` contains list of image paths : `["full/1182_Garishma1.jpg","full/K-Yukta-A.jpg"]`
So how do i show all the images in django admin panel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def product_Image(self):
    """Method to return store image for admin panel"""

    images = ''
    for image_path in self.image_paths:
        images += '<img src="/images/%s" height="150" width="150"/>' % image_path            
    return images
product_Image.allow_tags = True
```

without `product_Image.allow_tags = True` image will not be shown...

Answer (score 1):

Can't you loop over the path first?

```
def product_Image(self):
    """Method to return store image for admin panel"""

    images = ''
    for image_path in self.image_paths:
        images += '<img src="/images/%s" height="150" width="150"/>' % image_path

    return images
```